# How do I check whether I can access a file saved with NSFileProtectionKey = NSFileProtectionCompleteUntilFirstUserAuthentication

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I would like the determine if I have access to files that have been saved with the attribute `NSFileProtectionKey = NSFileProtectionCompleteUntilFirstUserAuthentication`.

I have tried [UIApplication sharedApplication].protectedDataAvailable, however from my tests it will return `NO` whenever the device is locked (if a pin code is set) even if the user has unlocked the device at least once since last starting the phone.

Answer (score -1):

It says quite clearly in the docs: The value of this property is NO if data protection is enabled and the device is currently locked, and in this case files that were assigned the NSFileProtectionComplete or NSFileProtectionCompleteUnlessOpen protection key cannot be read or written by your app. i.e. this is not the correct property.

You need use one of the multi-tasking keys that causes the launch the app on boot - e.g. the `voip` key for `UIBackgroundModes`.

> Mind you, you're pretty much testing the OS at that point - if you set the keys appropriately when creating the files it should work as advertised. If it doesn't then log a radar.

Comment: Yes I understand the docs point out that [UIApplication sharedApplication].protectedDataAvailable isn't going to do what I want but thanks for noting that.

However to be clear my problem isn't launching in the background (I'm using significant location), it is knowing whether I have access to my NSFileProtectionCompleteUntilFirstUserAuthentication protected file or not.

Comment: In recent experiments I've noticed that if I try and access the file when I don't have access I end up with an empty NSData object. However I am able to verify its on disk and has a size. At this stage this is the best option I've found. To your point though this is testing the OS rather than a stable approach.

Comment: Ah, the question makes a lot more sense now. It doesn't seem as though there's an obvious way to check for this state. Maybe something like the `applicationProtectedDataWillBecomeAvailable` handler may allow you to detect when the data becomes available so that you can now access it.

Comment: Thanks Petesh, but isn't applicationProtectedDataWillBecomeAvailable just notifying me of changes to the protectedDataAvailable state? If so I'm not sure I see how that would help me?